# How to alter attributes of datatable jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When the page is loaded , i am passing serverside as false, but in some conditions in want to set serverside as true without changing other attributes.
Example:

```
$(tableID).DataTable({
    serverSide : false;
});
```

To:

```
$(tableID).DataTable({
    serverSide : true;
});
```

But its throwing DataTables warning : Cannot reinitise Datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is triggered by passing in options to a DataTables constructor object when the DataTable instance for the selected node has already been initialised.

```
$(tableID).DataTable( {
    destroy: true,
    serverSide : false
} );
```

**[destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())** : Destroy the DataTables in the current context.

Comment: Hi @Rino Raj , Will it remove other set attributes as well?

Comment: @user3932103 yes. You have to initialize all the attributes again